# Order By on Joined Entity - Doctrine Query Builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have the following query:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('a')
    ->from('CatalogueBundle\Entity\Avantage','a')
    ->leftJoin('a.avantagegrilles', 'g')
    ...
    ->orderBy('a.avantageOrdre', 'ASC');
```

The result of the query is as follows:

[image]

An `avantage` can contain several `avantagegrilles`. Now there is a variable in entity `avantagegrille` called `avantagegrilleMini` and I want to do an `order by asc` on it; that is, when an `avantage` is returned, its `avantagegrilles` are ordered according to their `avantagegrilleMini`.

I added `->orderBy('g.avantagegrilleMini', 'ASC')` to the query but it didn't have any effect. Is what I want to implement possible in Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this line: `->orderBy('g.avantageOrdre', 'ASC');`